# No fans detected

Tags: drivers, fan, overheating, temperature, compatibility

I have an Acer Aspire 3 A315-53 with a KBL metapod motherboard and ever since I switched to Ubuntu the fans haven't spun (they worked before with Windows 10).
I've already run `sensors` and `xsensors` in the cli but the result is this:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +39.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

There seems to be no information whatsoever about any kind of voltage nor fanspeed.

Also, when running the command `fancontrol` this is what I obtain:

```
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Error: Can't read configuration file
```

I don't really know what `pwmconfig` does, but when I tried to type it this happened:

```
~$ sudo pwmconfig
# pwmconfig revision 6243 (2014-03-20)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

So, yeah, I'm starting to accept the fact that my hardware simply isn't compatible, but is there something else I can do?

I'm not very savy when it comes to computers but I've spent hours and even reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it's stayed the same.

Thank you for your time.

Btw `sudo sensors-detect` outputs this:

```
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: Acer Aspire A315-53 [V1.21] (laptop)
# Board: KBL Metapod_KL
# Kernel: 5.0.0-25-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz (6/142/9)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): yes
/dev/port: Operation not permitted

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): yes
/dev/port: Operation not permitted

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): yes
Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:9d23 at 0000:00:1f.4.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.
Client at address 0x2c can not be probed - unload all client drivers first!

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: DPDDC-A (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo sensors-detect`?

Comment: yeah and i awnsered yes to every question, would you be interested in the output so you could help me figure out the problem?

Comment: Sure - add it to your question.

Comment: there it is, what can i extract from that?

Comment: There's nothing to extract, I'm afraid. Maybe you can try a different distro (in a Live setting) and see what it can see.

Comment: does that mean hopping to arch or manjaro could solve the problem?

Comment: It's possible. Could be the kernel version, so I'd try something on the cutting edge (like Fedora) as well as something older (like Mint).

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the `pwmconfig` output, your laptop does not have pwm-capable sensor modules installed. So, as far as I know, there isn't a way to manually control your fans' speed. You have to rely on automatic control.

Your CPUs' temperatures are pretty low, by the way, and it could be the reason why you cannot hear your fan spinning.

You can check, however, if your fan is working by doing a simple stress test:

1. Open your terminal and run:

   ```
   python3
   ```

   This will open a python prompt.
2. Copy and paste (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) the following code in the python prompt.

   ```py
   i = 1
   while True:
       print(i)
       i += 1
   ```

   Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> 2 times to run the code.

   This code is a very simple [infinite loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop) that just prints a number in the terminal and then increases it by 1, over and over again. It will make your CPUs get hotter, causing the fans to spin after a few seconds.
3. If your fans begin to spin, great! They work as they should! If not, you have to further search for a solution.

   You can stop the program any time by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and close the python prompt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

You can also monitor your CPU temperature while running the stress test by opening another terminal window and running the command:

```
watch -n 1 sensors
```

This will run `sensors` every 1 second. You can stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: thank you! i guess i just have to accept the fact that my hardware doesn't support that kind of manual tweaking, but does that mean it is impossible for me to measure my fan speed using my software?

Comment: Yes, that's the case for now. Perhaps a future kernel update will give you this capability.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog I am using a dekstop with an Asus motherboard and by running the python stress test in your answer I can get the fans to spin noticeably faster and louder, but when I try to run pwmconfig I still get the `no pwm-capable sensor modules installed` message. What I would like to do is simply setting a lower fan speed for when the system is idle, similar to what I am doing in windows by using asus software (on silent profile). Do you have any idea what I could try? Thanks!

Comment: @Redoman Hi! Your case is the same as in the question, so my answer applies to yours as well: Since `pwmconfig` says `no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`, you cannot alter the fan speed with `pwmconfig`. I don't know of any other way that you could do that, so if you find one, please also let me know! :)

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog FYI I just tried another linux distro (Pop!_OS) and on first boot it was able to automatically manage fan speed without any intervention from my side and it was actually able to stop fans completely when nothing was running. Not sure what software Pop!_OS is using the hood in order to accomplish that, but if I find more I will try to report here.